# babel stage 0 syntax highlighting in webstorm / intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, babeljs

I do like jetbrains' IDEs but when I tried to use babel with do expression like

```
let a = do {
  if(false)
    'Nay'
  else
    'Yay'
}
```

Same thing happens to `::` function bind as well.

The syntax highlighting just messed up because webstorm / intellij idea believe there is a syntax error.

Is there a configuration for this, or just some walk around exists?

Comment: I think that one-line expression with else statement isn't allowed, probably you need for a ternary operator...

Comment: yeah, you're right, one-liner with else would be a syntax error. edited

Comment: Yeah, This is... Anyway what do {} means?? Are you missing a while statement?

Comment: that's do expression in stage 0, see: [stage-0](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/blob/master/stage0.md)

Comment: and now already available in babel stage-0 presets [do-expressions-transform](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-do-expressions/)

Answer (score 2):

Function bind is there since WebStorm 11.0.3 - see [WEB-16614](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16614).
Do expressions aren't yet supported, please vote for [WEB-20609](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20609)